# Deploy ExpressJS with React in docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, express

I want to deploy my  application,  which is  using expressJS as backend and  React on front-end side.  I want to deploy it and  run  in docker-contatiner. I' m using http-proxy-middleware for redirect requests to expressjs backend. My  docker-file is like this:

```
 # base image
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
COPY client/package.json /usr/src/app/client/package.json

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/client

RUN npm  install  --silent

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "run" , "dev"]
```

And this is my package.json commands:

```
"server": "nodemon index.js",
"client": "cd client && npm start",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
```

But I know that production of React I need to make build. But is that neccessary? Because this  docker is running correctly, but is it good  for production server? I think that I need to build React part before deployment and also do something with  expressjs part. Can someone explain to me what is neccessary to make good production deployment through docker-container?

My application structure is following:

```
/client - contatins react part ( src, public, build, package.json,  etc)
/server - conatins expressjs part
package.json - contains commands to run 
index.js - start of server
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: better to copy the build to docker file, instead of building in the container boot time. build consume and suck the system. container are desgined to be light weight and boot time should be minimum. better to run separate container. one processes per container. backend and frontend should be in different.

Comment: Hm it should be in one docker container, because i need to push them to one live environment where i can just put one container... so maybe build client, and then run docker container with reading just build folder in it? ... and what anout deployment of expressjs,that doesnt require build?

Comment: yes for the frontend you should copy the build and for express the dockerfile seems right. for backend node application it standred way, but for frontend it should be build

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to run the npm run build in production because that will create your production-ready build, you need to add more command in your package.json file and same in your docker script file.

Package.json file

```
 "prod": "npm run build && npm run dev"
```

Docker File

```
CMD ["npm", "run" , "prod"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> but is it good for production server?

I'd offer two suggestions:

- Although you can build the client inside the container, it's better to install and build it prior to deployment and then copy the results of the build (.html files, script bundles, possibly even source maps for production build troubleshooting) using Docker COPY command. Generally it's preferable to keep the production environment as lean and mean as possible and avoid installing lots of packages not needed at run-time.
   
  That's what already has been suggested in the comments. So installing Express and its dependencies if fine, installing the client is not. This [technique](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) is commonly used to build clients written in Javascript and other languages.
- It's important not to run in production any software that is meant to be used in development only. webpack-dev-server falls into this cathegory. If that is what `npm run client` means, then it's not a good idea to run it outside dev environment.